# Ruby On Rails : How to add a link_to in a select_tag

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

```
 <%= select_tag "profile", options_from_collection_for_select(@profile, 'id','profile_blip'),:onchange => "window.location.replace('/'+this.value);" %>
```

In place `'id'` want to place some link is it possible in rails 

I am trying with below code not getting, please help me out.

```
<%= select_tag "profile", options_from_collection_for_select(@profile, "profile/publications",'profile_blip'),:onchange => "window.location.replace('/'+this.value);" %>
```

Comment: Don't use `options_from_collection_for_select` but build the choices object yourself. See the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select) for inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

options_from_collection_for_select create a erb code like this:

```
<option value="#{profile.id}">#{profile.profile_blip}</option>
```

Write a method in the model class "Profile" which returns what you want. Then change the select_tag to this:

```
<%= select_tag "profile", options_from_collection_for_select(@profile, "new_method_name",'profile_blip'),:onchange => "window.location.replace('/'+this.value);" %>
```